# Diffraction grating vs single slit

Tags: interference, diffraction

When I think about it, the single slit interference experiment should resemble the diffraction grating experiment as it is almost like single slit is the equivalent of a grating with many many many slits in a small length. So I would have though that the more slits you add in a diffraction grating, the closer its pattern of interference would resemble that of the single slit. However, it does not! The maximums become more and more distinct when adding more slits. Why do these two methods produce such different results? 
Thanks

Comment: Can you show more of your calculations? When I teach single slit diffraction, I introduce it by showing how it's exactly the same as the many-slit limit of a diffraction grating. You may be taking the limit incorrectly.

Comment: @knzhou The calculations would involve finding the intensity function of both patterns and are a little bit tedious. I will put them in this post tomorrow as it is late now. However, If you just compare images of single double and grating diffraction, the distinction is quite explicit. It can be seen in this image directly. https://goo.gl/images/tmHt3m  the grating produces various intense maximums and long black periods between them while the single slit produces a single very intense maximum and then quickly dies in intensity.

Comment: This is the result of taking the limits incorrectly. You're basically imagining carving out more and more slits, but you also need to bring the slits closer together, so that the total length of the grating stays the same.

Comment: Once you do this, the central maximum of the diffraction grating result turns into the single maximum of the single slit result.

Comment: @knzhou lets take light of 500nm. In the single slit (width = 0.1mm), we find the first maximum at an angle of 0.286 degrees. Now lets take a diffraction grating of the same width with 1000000 slits carved into it. The equation: dsin(x)= (lambda).   d=10^-10. Now the first maximum does not even appear on the screen. These are 2 very different results. Did i miss something?

Comment: We use this as an illustrative explanation all the time, but we usually leave out the nasty requirement on the math: you have to take the limit of many slits as the slit width drops such that the product of the number $N$ of hypothetical slits and the hypothetical slit spacing $d$ remains equal to the actual slit width $w$.

Answer (score 0):

The intensity patterns (with the maximum intensity scaled to be the same in each case) shown below are the effect of having the **same** slit width and the **same** slit separation but increasing the number of slits.
This means that the length of the grating increases as the number of slits increases.

[image]

It is the result of two effects the "diffraction$ of light by each of the slits and the interference of light from each of the slits.

So the diffraction grating can be thought of as $N$ slits each of width $b$ and centre to centre separation $a$.

[image]

The intensity $I(\theta)$ pattern for such an arrangement is given by

$$I(\theta) = I_o \left( \dfrac{\sin \beta}{\beta}\right)^2\left( \dfrac{\sin N\alpha}{\sin \alpha}\right)^2$$

where $I_o$ is the intensity at $\theta =0$ produced by a single slit, $\beta = \dfrac {\pi b}{\lambda}\sin\theta,\;\alpha= \dfrac {\pi a}{ \lambda}\sin\theta$ and $\lambda$ is the wavelength of light.

Suppose now you have $N$ slits each of width $a$ and the same separation $a$.
In effect this is a single slit of width $Na$.

With $\alpha = \beta$ the intensity pattern is

$$I(\theta) = I_o \left( \dfrac{\sin \alpha}{\alpha}\right)^2\left( \dfrac{\sin N\alpha}{\sin \alpha}\right)^2= N^2 I_o \left( \dfrac{\sin N\alpha}{N\alpha}\right)^2$$

with $N\alpha= \dfrac {\pi Na}{ \lambda}\sin\theta$ equivalent to a single slit of width $Na$ and $I_o$ the intensity of a **single** slit of width $a$.

This is the intensity pattern of a single slit of width $Na$ and the length of this "grating" is $Na$.

To have more and more slits in the same length of grating then that is just equivalent to keeping $Na$ constant and one still gets a single slit diffraction pattern of the correct intensity because as the number of slits increases the intensity due to a single slit decreases in proportion.

**Update** as a result of a comment

Note the diffraction envelope expanding as the slit width is decreased.

[image]

Comment: Only for my understanding, making the slit wider one would get diffraction pattern on the left and the right edges and between simple going through light without visible diffraction?